# Javascript: Parse JSON object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse the following data, which is a list of object from server. This is what I have after I using `JSON.stringify(data.d);` on the data:

```
"[{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"SSN","empValue":"a","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Birth_Date","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Department_Name","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"email","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"First_Name","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Sex","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Strata_ID","empValue":null,"isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"SSN","empValue":"b","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Birth_Date","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Department_Name","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"email","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"First_Name","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Sex","empValue":"","isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"},    
{"__type":"EditGridDemo.CellData","empProperty":"Strata_ID","empValue":null,"isValid":false,"comments":"Reason of what went wrong"}]"
```

It is a list of CellData, which consist of empProperty, empValue, isValid, comments as its attributes..I not able to access these properties in JS.

Comment: Parsing it will do the reverse of stringifying it. Why are you stringying it in the first place?

Comment: Previously, I was doing $.parseJSON(data.d), it gave undefined..

Comment: Why were you trying to parse something that is already a JavaScript object? Just use `data.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just start using data.d[i].empProperty and data.d[i].empValue as mentioned in some comments i is the index of the array. Do no stringify it, its already parsed into an object for you.

Read about JSON [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Answer (score -1):

The structure is an array of objects.
So you can access each element simply through the index:

```
var arr = JSON.stringify(data.d);
var item = arr[0];
```

Then you can access each property in different ways:

```
empValue = item.empValue;  //returns "a"
empProperty = item["empProperty"];  //returns "SSN"
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9WfN3/).

Comment: please add a comment besides your downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think that `var arr = JSON.stringify(data.d);` will set a string representation of data.d inside arr, so `arr[0]` will just return the first character of that string.

Comment: @Jackopo: Please, have a look ad the demo. It's working fine.

Comment: The demo doesn't use `var arr=JSON.stringify(data.d)`, it uses directly the data.

Answer (score -1):

I quote a section from the following link: **[JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)**

To defend against this, a JSON parser should be used. A JSON parser will recognize only JSON text, rejecting all scripts.

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data.d);
var myObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Comment: As Quentin mentioned in the above comments, Why would I parse an object, which is already a JS object into JSON...

Comment: You did on the object stringify, the way to put it to an object is: parse

Comment: But `data.d` was the **input** to stringify, not the output!